# Javascript Fetch Time vs XHR Network Time

Tags: javascript, performance, api, fetch-api

I have a basic code in javascript to fetch data via api call:

```
var t0 = performance.now();
fetch(
    'http://domain/service',
    { method: 'GET' }
  )
  .then( response => {
      //handle response...
       t1 = performance.now();
       console.log('Call to fetch-start took ' + (t1 - t0) + ' milliseconds.');
    } )
  .catch( error => console.error('error:', error) )
  .then( () => {
       ...
       t1 = performance.now();
       console.log('Call to fetch-end took ' + (t1 - t0) + ' milliseconds.');
    } );
```

When I call it, Chrome network time shows like:

[image]

But console shows like:

```
Call to fetch-start took 1931.162 milliseconds.
Call to fetch-end took 2846.36500000488 milliseconds.
```

I don't understand the difference between browser network time and fetch time. Both of them should be same?

Comment: Looks like `response.json()` took a lot of time?

Comment: Side note: It's not the problem, but like many people, you're running into the [footgun in the `fetch` API](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html). You need to check `response.ok`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because when `fetch` resolves with the Body object, only the negotiations and fetching of the headers have been done.
The fetching of the data is still ongoing, that's how we can [consume this Body as a stream.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams).

The closest to the actual end of fetching will be `Body.arrayBuffer()` which doesn't perform any transformation on the fetched data.